# Unable to install antlrworks2

Tags: installation, antlrworks2

I downloaded antlrworks2 from the tunnel vision labs website and tried to install it by running the antlrworks2.exe but getting the error "antlrworks2.exe is not a valid win32 application". I tried it on Win server 2003 as well as Win 7 32 bit but I got the same error.

I am using VS 2008 for development as the target language would be C#.

Is that the right way to install antlrworks? I believe antlrworks is a stand alone application or do I also need to install antlr? Has it got any dependency?

Answer (score 3):

I know of an issue where the problem you describe appears on Windows XP, but haven’t heard of this on Windows Vista or later. The problem will be fixed for ANTLRWorks 2.0.1.
[#7 Support running ANTLRWorks 2 on Windows XP](https://bitbucket.org/sharwell/antlrworks2/issue/7/support-running-antlrworks-2-on-windows-xp)

ANTLRWorks 2 requires you to install Java before running it. I am not sure whether or not it will work with just the JRE (runtime only) installed, so to be on the safe side I recommend installing the JDK (development kit). I recommend Java 7 for its performance advantages; the current release is 7u13.
[Java SE Development Kit 7 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)